# Should I use HTTPS for my WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress, security, https, blog

In general I am aware of what SSL does and how, but I'm not exactly sure as to what's the accepted custom, i.e. whether I actually am supposed to use it for my blog.

There will be no other users than me, no financial data circulating, and no truly critical information will be stored on the blog. However, I will still need to log in to the website from various places and devices.

SSL would enhance security, but could also lead to link rot in the future, is kind of a hassle, is a strain on the processor, and makes caching the website harder.

So, is it necessary to have my blog running over HTTPS? Is it a must-do in the community?

Comment: Also you may find http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/is-using-only-https-bad-in-a-seo-perspective useful in terms of SEO and many more which should help you make this decision <> http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ssl%20is%3aquestion#

Comment: Just curious as to why SSL could lead to "link rot"? (Unless maybe you are serving your site only via HTTPS and rejecting all HTTP requests - although that would simply make for an invalid link from the outset.) And what do you mean by "hashing the website"?

Comment: @w3d You go to my site, like an article, and share it somewhere. You copied an HTTPS link. Next, I decide to switch platforms, take care of the permalinks, but no longer have HTTPS enabled. Now all the links don't work because you copied the HTTPS one, not the HTTP one. And I meant "caching", not "hashing", I read that SSL makes it impossible to hash the site on various points, which makes sense. In the end, I realized that it's incredibly easy to enable HTTPS only for administration in WordPress, no redirects/rewrite rules required, only `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` and a SSL Virtual H.